# java: how can I pass a class and call its static members?

Tags: java

Just what the title says. I am trying to pass the a class to a function

```
f(MyType.class)
```

where

```
class MyType {
    static int g() {...}
}
```

Can the function that receives the class

```
void h(Class<MyType> cls) {...}
```

somehow access this method?

Comment: Not directly, that is not how static methods work, only with reflection you could acces something though I wouldnt recommend it. A better way would be to use a funtional interface, and let the user determine the actions against provided arguments(if nesseccary).

Answer (score 1):

Given that function h requires the class MyType to be passed, I can see no reason not to use the static access form of `MyType.g();`

Comment: Don't forget the scope of the method.

Comment: True. Though the sample code shared does not indicate that the scope is outside the package. Neither what the relevant usage of the `cls` parameter is in `h`.

Comment: For subclasses the parameter should have been `Class<? extends MyType>`. I'd strongly argument against it though, as the whole idea of instance methods is overloading, and for static methods it isnt .

Answer (score 1):

You could not invoke the `g()` method of your class as the parameter will rely on  the `Class` type. You could only invoke methods provided by `Class`.

What you try to do seems more natural by passing an instance of `MyType` and invoking a method instance on it.
If you defined  `g()` in multiples classes, define this method in an interface and makes these classes implement it.

Answer (score 1):

Technically you can do it by using reflection:

```
Class klass = ...;
Method m = klass.getDeclaredMethod(methodName, paramtypes);
m.invoke(null, args)
```

But its something not natural for java, It's better to pass into the function object of some interface that have this method like this:

```
interface MyType {
    int g();
}

void h(MyType myType) {
  myType.g();
}
```